# How do i pop up a window when a user taps on the particular row in my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

How to show a pop up window when the user clicks on the particular field in my table view.
It should pop a window ant it should display the user contact information.
I do not want to use navigationbar controller here.
Kindly help me

Comment: you want to create UIPopOverViewController

Comment: if you want this for iPhone then UIPopOverController will not help you.

Comment: @priyanka yeah you are right. he needs to clear about iPhone or iPad?

Comment: yeah, i am creating this application for iphone

Comment: @Cocoa Matters but tag is specified this post is for iPhone.

Comment: @varma you have to create tableview according to your need frame and add above your view

Comment: @Cocoa Matters I have created my table view and am able to display the contact information on console when we clicking on particular field.

Comment: you can use customize alert view to pop up window https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: @varma then have look to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to display less details then you can use following option. 
declare below code in .h file

```
UIWindow *alertWindow;
```

Write following code in .m file.

```
    alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; // you must release the window somewhere, when you do not need it anymore
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert; // puts it above the status bar
    alertWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    /*CUSTOM VIEW obj*/.center = CGPointMake(alertWindow.frame.size.width/2, alertWindow.frame.size.height/2);
    [alertWindow addSubview:/*PUT YOUR CUSTOM VIEW HERE*/];
    [alertWindow setHidden:NO];
```

this code is display you custom view like UIAlertView.

you put above code in UITableView Delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

For hide window

```
[alertWindow setHidden:YES];
[alertWindow release]; alertWindow = nil;
```

Comment: vSortOption.center = CGPointMake(alertWindow.frame.size.width/2, alertWindow.frame.size.height/2); can u plz explain what this statement does exactly??

Comment: vSortOption // is my custom view which i create in xib and attach using IBOutlet. Ex IBOutlet UIView *vSortOption;

Answer (score 1):

I have written code of UIPopOverController with DatePicker as a example for you. just refer this example and set according your need

```
   -(IBAction)tDriveBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    txtDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                    [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [df release];

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [doneBtn release];
    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [barItems release];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    CGRect pickerRect = datePicker.bounds;
    datePicker.bounds = pickerRect;

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 344)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300);
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;

    //resize the popover view shown
    //in the current view to the view's size
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 244);

    //create a popover controller
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[tDriveBtn frame] 
                                       fromView:[tDriveBtn superview]];

    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100) ; 
    popoverRect.origin.x  = popoverRect.origin.x; 
    // popoverRect.size.height  = ; 

    [popoverController 
     presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
     inView:self.view 
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
     animated:YES];


    //release the popover content
    [popoverView release];
    [popoverContent release];

}
-(void)dateChange:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    txtDate.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                   [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [df release];
}
- (void)pickerDone:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    txtDate.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                   [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [df release];

    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController=nil;
    }  
}
```

Comment: can u help me without creating a pop over viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can display your new viewController using `presentModalViewController` method. I use it like this way:

```
- (IBAction)addNewBuidling:(id)sender
 {

    NewBuilding *new=[[NewBuilding alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewBuilding" bundle:nil];
           new.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    new.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:new animated:YES];

    new.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 357 ,117);//it's important to do this after. Take a frame size exactly of your new viewController's size.
    new.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
    [new release];
 }
```

This is how my `NewBuilding` viewController will appear on screen.

[image]

> Edit 1:

In this written in `presentModalViewController` reference: "**On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of modalViewController is always presented full screen.**" so for iPhone it may not serve your purpose.